# Run a Gradle plugin task when Gradle build is running (not manually from command line)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, gradlew

There is gradle plugin task that can be run from commandline like this -

```
$ ./gradlew runThisPlugin
```

But I want this plugin task to execute when gradle build is running (after I hit 'Run' or 'Rebuild' in Android studio). I am actually trying to eliminate the manual work here.

Is there any way to configure the plugin or gradle to run this task automatically when I build the project instead of running it manually from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation:

The default run/debug configuration launches the default project activity and uses the Select Deployment Target dialog for target device selection. If the default settings don't suit your project or module, you can customize the run/debug configuration, or even create a new one, at the project, default, and module levels. To edit a run/debug configuration, select **Run > Edit Configurations**.

The dialog looks like this:
[image: Run configuration dialog]

In the bottom right part of the screen, there is a **Before launch** menu.

Click on the **+** sign, and select **Run Gradle Task**

[image: Add new configuration dialog]

A **Select Gradle Task** dialog will appear.

[image: Select Gradle Task dialog]

Here select **Gradle Project** that you want, and **Tasks** that you want to run.

Click **Ok** two times and you are done.

Note that you task will be run **before** the build.

Here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html#opening) to official documentation.

Comment: You are my savior! I have been struggling with this for so many days. Thank you so so much for taking out time towrite such an elaborate anwer 

Comment: @UtkarshTiwari np. If this answer solves your problem, you can accept it https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Since I have to manually add this config, it would be great if It automatically gets configured when someone pulls and build my project on Android studio. One might forget to setup this config so it would be helpful if there is some way to automatically configure it programmatically maybe from gradle.build or something?

Comment: @UtkarshTiwari There are a few ways of doing this. Try [this](http://trickyandroid.com/gradle-tip-3-tasks-ordering/)